# How encode / in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, encoding

[image]

I have these events, and I want to search for events by name by clicking on the event name. I've done all the logic of the server, but I have a problem: encode the URL.

I need encode the /.

If I click on any of them, will redirect me to

`20/11/11%20Evento%20Free%20Pass`

when should be

```
20%2F11%2F11%20Evento%20Free%20Pass
```

I am using Node.js.

How fix that? Should i do in the client or in the server???

Update:

```
                        <tr class="reservas">
                            <td> <a class="fullEventName" href="/admin/bookings/1/<%= booking[i].fullEventName %>"><%= booking[i].fullEventName %> </a></td>
                        </tr>
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fullEventName').on('click', function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');


        var position = href.indexOf('=');
        var getDate = href.substring(position + 19);

        alert(getDate);

        var newChar = "%2F";
        var changeDateFormat = getDate.split('/').join(newChar);


        var newLink = '/admin/bookings/1/' + changeDateFormat;

        $(this).attr('href', newLink);
    });
});
```

This is working, but i dont think this is the better way..

Comment: You should use `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: in the client or in the server??

Comment: Probably in the client. Where and how are you encoding the url?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta @DaniloValente

Comment: That screenshot adds nothing to the question and takes up a lot of space. Was that truly necessary?

Comment: is just for better understand @tadman

Comment: @SuchMuchFunny It actually confuses your question and distracts from what's important.

Comment: Consider slugifying the string if you want to put it in the url, i.e. replace anything that's not an alphanumeric ascii character with a dash.

Comment: @SuchMuchFunny alexpods has the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both on the client and on the server (node.js) you can use `encodeURIComponent`. In that case you should use it on server:

```
<tr class="reservas">
    <td> 
    <a href="/admin/bookings/1/<%= encodeURIComponent(booking[i].fullEventName) %>" class="fullEventName" >
        <%= booking[i].fullEventName %>
    </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: LOL!!!!! I cant believe i can do that!!! hahaha.. thanks very muchh!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!